# How can I apply CSS onto HTML tag directly?

Tags: html, hover, tooltip

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title of the document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span title="Hello world!">Hover this text to see the result.</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have a lot of information to put inside the hover text and when I make the screen smaller my text goes beyond the screen (it's not responsive). Is there a way I can add styles within the  tag? I tried creating a tooltip class and because of the project structure I am unable to see the label itself.

Could I add `style=display:block;` or something similar like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS can be added to HTML documents in 3 ways:

Inline - by using the style attribute inside HTML elements

Internal - by using a  element in the  section

External - by using a  element to link to an external CSS file

For your purposes you would do something like this:

```
<p style="property:value;">Some text</p>
<h1 style="color:blue;">A Blue Heading</h1>
etc...
```

UPDATE:

Keep in mind that this won't fix your problem with responsiveness of the website itself for that you need to use `CSS Media Queries`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

UPDATE 2 (STYLING TITLE ATTRIBUTE):

There is a pure `CSS` solution, by setting `CSS` `attr` expression, generated content and attribute selectors (which suggests that it works as far back as IE8):

```
span[title]:hover::after {
  content: attr(title);
  position: absolute;
  top: -100%;
  left: 0;
}
```

Comment: is adding styles to the title attribute an option? ```<span title="Hello world!">Hover this text to see the result.</span>```

Comment: Yes, there is. I have updated my answer - check it once again.
@NickH